# How to use phase control of inlining in haskell?

Tags: performance, haskell, ghc, inlining, repa

Documentation [says](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#phase-control),

> Sometimes you want to control exactly when in GHC's pipeline the INLINE pragma is switched on.

Why should I ever want this? (Except when I also use RULES pragma, in this case I may want to postpone inlining of the function in order to let associated rules to be fired.) What kinds of functions are better to inline only at a particular stage of simplifying process?

Comment: you pretty much described when you want it

Comment: Take a look at `repa` source code: major part of functions has different phase control numbers: 0, 1, 2, 4. But there aren't any RULES in the package.

Comment: @leventov: `repa` may not define rules, but it's based on `vector`, which most assuredly does.  It's not entirely clear at first glance though, because the `vector` source also relies heavily on CPP.  Anyway, `repa`s phase control numbers are tuned to interact with the RULES and INLINEs used by `vector`.

Comment: +1 @luqui.  You have correctly deduced that it's really only useful when there are also RULES you want to have a chance to fire before inlining occurs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You essentially answered your own question, as others stated. But I imagine you might want a more cut-down and concrete example of where using phase control in combination with `RULES`/`INLINE` is beneficial.* You don't see them beyond heavily optimized libraries which are often complex, so it's great to see smaller cases.

Here is an example I implemented recently, using recursion schemes. We will illustrate this using the concept of catamorphisms. You don't need to know what those are in detail, just that they characterize 'fold' operators. (Really, do not focus too much on the abstract concepts here. This is just the simplest example I have, where you can have a nice speed-up.)

### Quick intro to catamorphisms

We begin with `Mu`, the fix-point type, and a definition of `Algebra` which is just a fancy synonym for a function which "deconstructs" a value of `f a` to return an `a`.

```
newtype Mu f = Mu { muF :: f (Mu f) }

type Algebra f a = f a -> a
```

We may now define two operators, `ffold` and `fbuild`, which are highly-generic versions of the traditional `foldr` and `build` operators for lists:

```
ffold :: Functor f => Algebra f a -> Mu f -> a
ffold h = go h 
  where go g = g . fmap (go g) . muF
{-# INLINE ffold #-}

fbuild :: Functor f => (forall b. Algebra f b -> b) -> Mu f
fbuild g = g Mu
{-# INLINE fbuild #-}
```

Roughly speaking, `ffold` *destroys* a structure defined by an `Algebra f a` and yields an `a`. `fbuild` instead *creates* a structure defined by its `Algebra f a` and yields a `Mu` value. That `Mu` value corresponds to whatever recursive data type you're talking about. Just like regular `foldr` and `build`: we deconstruct a list using its cons, and we build a list using its cons, too. The idea is we've just generalized these classic operators, so they can work over *any* recursive data type (like lists, or trees!)

Finally, there is a law that accompanies these two operators, which will guide our overall `RULE`:

```
forall f g. ffold f (build g) = g f
```

This rule essentially generalizes the optimization of deforestation/fusion - the removal of the intermediate structure. (I suppose the proof of correctness of said law is left as an exercise to the reader. Should be rather easy via equational reasoning.)

We may now use these two combinators, along with `Mu`, to represent recursive data types like a list. And we can write operations over that list.

```
data ListF a f = Nil | Cons a f
  deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)
type List a = Mu (ListF a)

instance Eq a => Eq (List a) where
  (Mu f) == (Mu g) = f == g

lengthL :: List a -> Int
lengthL = ffold g
  where g Nil = 0
        g (Cons _ f) = 1 + f
{-# INLINE lengthL #-}
```

And we can define a `map` function as well:

```
mapL :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
mapL f = ffold g
  where g Nil = Mu Nil
        g (Cons a x) = Mu (Cons (f a) x)
{-# INLINE mapL #-}
```

## Inlining FTW

We now have a means of writing terms over these recursive types we defined. However, if we were to write a term like

```
lengthL . mapL (+1) $ xs
```

Then if we expand the definitions, we essentially get the composition of two `ffold` operators:

```
ffold g1 . ffold g2 $ ...
```

And that means we're actually destroying the structure, then rebuilding it and destroying *again*. That's really wasteful. Also, we can re-define `mapL` in terms of `fbuild`, so it will hopefully fuse with other functions.

Well, we already have our law, so a `RULE` is in order. Let's codify that:

```
{-# RULES
-- Builder rule for catamorphisms
"ffold/fbuild" forall f (g :: forall b. Algebra f b -> b).
                  ffold f (fbuild g) = g f
-}
```

Next, we'll redefine `mapL` in terms of `fbuild` for fusion purposes:

```
mapL2 :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
mapL2 f xs = fbuild (\h -> ffold (h . g) xs)
  where g Nil = Nil
        g (Cons a x) = Cons (f a) x
{-# INLINE mapL2 #-}
```

Aaaaaand we're done, right? Wrong!

### Phases for fun and profit

The problem is there are zero constraints on when inlining occurs, which will completely mess this up. Consider the case earlier that we wanted to optimize:

```
lengthL . mapL2 (+1) $ xs
```

We would like the definitions of `lengthL` and `mapL2` to be inlined, so that the `ffold/fbuild` rule may fire afterwords, over the body. So we want to go to:

```
ffold f1 . fbuild g1 ...
```

via inlining, and after that go to:

```
g1 f1
```

via our `RULE`.

Well, that's not guaranteed. Essentially, in one phase of the simplifier, GHC may not *only* inline the definitions of `lengthL` and `mapL`, but it may also inline the definitions of `ffold` and `fbuild` at their use sites. This means that the RULE will never get a chance to fire, as the phase 'gobbled up' all of the relevant identifiers, and inlined them into nothing.

The observation is that we would like to inline `ffold` and `fbuild` *as late as possible*. Thus, we will try to expose as many possible opportunities as possible for our RULE to fire. And if it doesn't, then the body will get inlined, and GHC will still give its best. But ultimately, we want it to inline late; the `RULE` will save us more efficiency than any clever compiler optimization.

So the fix here is to annotate `ffold` and `fbuild` and specify they should only fire at phase 1:

```
ffold g = ...
{-# INLINE[1] ffold #-}

fbuild g = ...
{-# INLINE[1] fbuild #-}
```

Now, `mapL` and friends will be inlined very early, but these will come very late. GHC begins from some phase number N, and the phase numbers decrease to zero. Phase 1 is the last phase. It would also be possible to inline `fbuild/ffold` sooner than Phase 1, but this would essentially mean you need to start increasing the number of phases to make up for it, or start making sure the RULE always fires in some earlier stages.

### Conclusion

You can find [all of this and more in a gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/thoughtpolice/4411740)**, with all the mentioned definitions and examples here. It also comes with a criterion benchmark of our example: with our phase annotations, GHC is able to cut the runtime of `lengthL . mapL2` in half compared to `lengthL . mapL1`, when the `RULE` fires.

If you would like to see this yourself, you can compile the code with the `-ddump-simpl-stats`, and see that the `ffold/fbuild` rule fired during the compilation pipeline.

Finally, most of the same principles apply to libraries like vector or bytestring. The trick is that you may have multiple levels of inlining here, and a *lot* more rules. This is because techniques like stream/array fusion tend to effectively fuse loops and reuse arrays - as opposed to here, where we just do classical deforestation, by removing an intermediate data structure. Depending on the traditional 'pattern' of code generated (say, due to a vectorized, parallel list comprehension) it may very much be worth it to interleave or specifically phase optimizations in a way that obvious deficiencies are eliminated earlier on. Or, optimize for cases where a `RULE` in combination with an `INLINE` will give rise to more `RULE`s (hence the staggered phases you see sometimes - this basically interleaves a phase of inlining.) For these reasons, you can also control the phases in which a `RULE` fires.

So, while `RULE`s with phases can save us a lot of runtime, they can take a lot of time to get right too. This is why you often see them only in the most 'high performance', heavily optimized libraries.

### Notes

- * Your original question was "what kinds of functions benefit from phase control" which to me sounds like asking "which functions benefit from constant subexpression elimination." I am not sure how to accurately answer this, if it's even possible! This is more of a compiler-realm thing, than any theoretical result about how functions or programs behave - even *with* mathematical laws, not all 'optimizations' have the results you expect. As a result, the answer is effectively "you'll probably know when you write and benchmark it."
- ** You can safely ignore a lot of other stuff in the file; it was mostly a playground, but may be interesting to you too. There are other examples like naturals and binary trees in there - you may find it worthwhile to try exploiting various other fusion opportunities, using them.

Answer (score 1):

First, I should note that GHC's default behavior is designed to be mostly optimal in most situations. Unless you have a problem, you are probably best off letting the very smart people who think about haskell all day everyday be mostly right (P.S. I am *not* one of those people), but you asked...

There are to my understanding two reasons for using this.

1. Make the program converge to it's best form faster:

   Haskell will try each rules pass repeatedly as long as what comes out the other end is strictly better then what it started with. It will always converge, but there is nothing saying it will do so before the heat death of the universe.  In the common case it takes no more then a hand full of passes, but there are some corner cases that can be made pathologically bad.  This will allow you to manually work around those edge cases if they occur.
2. Avoid converging to a local minimum

   There are some cases where applying Rule `A` will prevent the application of a better Rule `B`.  It is then important that `B` come before `A`.  The default optimization rules are well crafted to avoid this problem, but as the documentation says they are also very conservative.  As you add more rules, you will inevitably begin to break other possible optimizations. You will then need to find a place in the rules chain where this doesn't happen. To the best of my knowledge the only way to tell is by trial and error.